# Linux Sorting based on different column in file names

Tags: linux, sorting

Can you please help me on sorting the file names by a couple of conditions?

`ls -tr | grep ${DATE}* | sort -k1`

```
        dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
        dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
        dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
        dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
        dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
        dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
        dboption_04Export_DDL_AFTER_CHANGE_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sh
        dboption_04Export_DDL_AFTER_CHANGE_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sh
        dboption_05drop_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
        dboption_05drop_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
        dboption_06aftertablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
        dboption_06aftertablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
        dboption_07afterschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
        dboption_07afterschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
```

I want the output should be: database, schema, and then file number

A_IS_CRB is the db and CTL,CDS are schema. (It can also have different db names)

I want to process all 7 files for one database one schema and then proceed with other 7 files of same database different schema or different database with some schema .

I tried a couple of things:

```
    ls -tr | grep ${DATE}* | sort -k1
    ls -tr | grep ${DATE}* | sort -t $'_'  -k4 -k5 -k2,2
    ls -tr | grep ${DATE}* | grep "  awk -F'[0-9]_' '{print $NF}' |awk -F_ '{print $NF}' |sed 's/.sql//' |sed 's/.sh//' | sed 's/\_$//'| uniq"  (to grep schema)
```

No luck, any help much appreciated. The desired output is:

```
 dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
    dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
    dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
    dboption_04Export_DDL_AFTER_CHANGE_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sh
    dboption_05drop_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
    dboption_06aftertablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
    dboption_07afterschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
    dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
    dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
    dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
    dboption_04Export_DDL_AFTER_CHANGE_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sh
    dboption_05drop_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
    dboption_06aftertablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
    dboption_07afterschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
```

Comment: `database, schema, and then file number` Which information is database, which is schema (what is a schema) and where is filenumber stored? The format is of filename is `<database>_<filenumber><???><ignore the rest>`?

Answer (score 0):

I isolated the names of the files in two tables then I displayed them at the end of the processing

```
awk '$0 ~ /_CDS/{cds[$0]} $0 ~ /_CTL/{ ctl[$0]} END{for(i in cds){print i} for(ii in ctl){print ii}}'  your_file
```

Tell me if this solution is right for you.

Comment: Thanks mchelabi , sorry for the confussion , CTL and CDS are just example and it can be anything , i have explained more below , many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you want to sort by db-schema so you can process 1-7 of the files with `CDS` schema and then 1-7 with the `CTL` schema. You can do that using `awk` split to isolate the db-schema, outputting the entire record followed by the db-schema to allow sorting and then use `awk` again to drop the second db-schema sort column, e.g.

```
awk -F'-' '{split($2,a,"_"); print $0" "substr(a[5],1,3)}' listing | 
sort -k2 | 
awk '{print $1}'
```

**Example Output**

With your input in the `listing` file, you would receive:

```
dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
dboption_04Export_DDL_AFTER_CHANGE_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sh
dboption_05drop_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
dboption_06aftertablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
dboption_07afterschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sql
dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
dboption_04Export_DDL_AFTER_CHANGE_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sh
dboption_05drop_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
dboption_06aftertablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
dboption_07afterschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CTL.sql
```

Let me know if you need changes to this output.

---

**Edit - Update Per-Format Change Delimiting dbname and schema with '-'**

In the comments when you advised that the db-name and db-schema were not fixed with the db-name having two `'_'` delimiters and none in the db-schema, that created a problem where what constituted the db-name and what was the db-schema was now ambiguous. There being no way to know whether you have a 3-part (two `'_'`) name and 2-part (one `'_'`) schema or a 4-part name (three `'_'`) and a 1-part schema (no `'_'`) (or any of the other 6 or 7 combinations between 3-5 part names and 1-3 part schema).

Adding the `'-'` as the delimiter between the db-name and db-schema now provides a non-ambiguous way to isolate the db-schema from the filename regardless of the number of parts separated by `'_'` in the db-name and db-schema. You can use `'-'` as the delimiter for `awk` and then `$NF` becomes the last field. (db-schema plus extension). Then using `substr($NF, 1, match($1, /[.]/) - 1)` you can isolate the db-schema alone.

```
awk -F'-' '{ print $0" "substr($NF,1,match($NF,/[.]/)-1) }' listing | 
sort -k2 | 
awk '{print $1}'
```

**Short Example Input**

```
$ cat listing
dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CDS.sql
dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CTS.sql
dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CDS.sql
dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CTS.sql
dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CDS.sql
dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CTS.sql
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F'-' '{ print $0" "substr($NF,1,match($NF,/[.]/)-1) }' listing |
> sort -k2 |
> awk '{print $1}'
dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CDS.sql
dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CDS.sql
dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CDS.sql
dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CTS.sql
dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CTS.sql
dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_FOO_IS_CRB-PDO_CTS.sql
```

If you want to maintain the extension as part of the db-schema, (I see you have both `.sql` and `.sh` extensions) then simply use the following as the first `awk` command

```
awk -F'-' '{ print $0" "$NF }` listing
```

Give it a go with your updated names and let me know if there are any hiccups.

---

**Additional Sort By DBSchema, then DBName, then FileNo.**

In order to sort by all the additional parameters you list, you will need to change the primary field delimiter to something that allows each of the fields to be separated and the information needed to sort extracted from the fields. A good choice would simply be to use `'-'` to separate the fields as:

```
Option  fileno_stuff  date  time  dbname  dbschema
```

That would correspond to an example record of, e.g.:

```
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914-FOO_PDA-BAR_CDS.sql
```

If you make those changes to your listing, then you can add three columns to your listing, (e.g. `fileno`, `dbname`, `dbschema`) allowing you to then `sort -k4 -k3 -k2n`. To append the fields and sort the new data, you could do:

```
awk -F'-' '{print $0" "substr($2,1,match($2,/[^0-9]+/)-1)+0" "$(NF-1)" "substr($NF,1,match($NF,/[.]/)-1)}' listing | 
sort -k4 -k3 -k2n | 
awk '{print $1}'
```

**Example Input Listing**

```
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDT.sql
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDT.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDT.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
```

**Sorted Output**

```
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDT.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDT.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDT.sql
```

When you have a reformatted listing, give it a try and let me know of any issues.

Comment: Hi David , This works absolutely perfecrt , ls -tr | grep ${DATE}* | awk -F'-' '{split($2,a,"_"); print $0" "substr(a[5],1,3)}'  | sort -k2 | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: but one more question please , for example if the database name have different length and different pattern and the same with schema will this work ??

Comment: Like database name like ORACLE_USER and schema name as ADMIN or database as ORACLE_DEV_USERS and schema name as ADMIN22 ??

Comment: till this it will be same dboption_01{beforeschemasize}_20200710-092914_   will be same , after that dbname and schema name can be anything and obviously  this will change {beforeschemasize} for all 7 files , thanks in advance

Comment: When i checked with db name as one word , it is giving wrong result .  one more standard pattern will be , the file name will end with .sql or .sh and the schema name will be the string after last underscore and before .sql or .sh and similarly the db name will be string between after timestamp (20200710-092914_) and before the above schema name pattern

Comment: Name length doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is the db-schema length -- it's just picking the first 3 chars from that -- but you could simply use the entire field `a[5]` instead of `substr(a[5],1,3)`. Your call. If you have millions of records like this, you can actually do it in a single call to `awk`, but that would take a could more rules.

Comment: Oh, if you look at the `awk -F"-"` it splits the name in two to grab the db-name and db-schema. If you re-post a representative set of what all the filenames can be, I'll be happy to accommodate whatever is there. It is impossible to know what all different forms your filenames may take without a full representative set. Also note above, the split is just to isolate the db-schema and add that as a new column at the end to allow sorting, the actual filename is never altered -- note the `print $0 ...` where `$0` is the complete unaltered filename.

Comment: Many thanks David , 97 % of the dbname is like 3 strings seperate by underscore A_IS_CRB and other 1 % is like P_CDS_MRT_S_TMP or P_CDS_MRT_S_W other 1% is like DIL_USR or SS_TMP and last 1 % is just one word ORACLE or EBBS etc

Comment: and sorry the schema Pattern which i mentioned above is not 100 % . the schema name will be that starts after underscore of db name for exmple  {db_name}_CTS.sql or {DBNAME)_DPO_DD.sql or {DB_NAME}_DPO_DD_SAM.sql or {dbname}_DIL_EGS_STAGING

Comment: Sorry David , not sure how diffuclt is this

Comment: It's not that it is difficult -- it is that the naming pattern is ambiguous. When processing each record (line), there is no way to know whether you have a 3-part (two `'_'`) name and 2-part (one `'_'`) schema or a 4-part name (three `'_'`) and a 1-part schema (no `'_'`) (or any of the other 6 or 7 combinations between 3-5 part names and 1-3 part schema. Is there any other indicator encoded in the line that tells you how many parts the name is and how many parts the schema is? If the name and schema were separated by a different delimiter like `'-'` instead of the same `'_'` it would be easy.

Comment: Thanks David , Will it work if the file name are changed liked this                                          dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql?? also i have one '-' in the timestamp does that matters ?? if not can you please share the code with new file strcture please .. Thanks in Advance David , appreciate it , thanks

Comment: Yes -- that works. There we can split the name and schema based on `'-'` and know which we have. I'll have time in a bit to update the answer.

Comment: Perfect David , many many thanks , waiting for an update .. Cheers

Comment: Hi David , Good Luck !!! Any luck for me David ? Thanks

Comment: ?? I thought it was all working -- that's good right? Let me know if there are other issues.

Comment: Sorry David , if different db has same schema it not working as expected it should be sorted filenumber ,then by db name and then by schema name

Comment: awk -F'-' '{ print $0" "substr($NF,1,match($NF,/[.]/)-1) }' listing |  sort -k2 |  awk '{print $1}'
dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption_01beforeschemasize_20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption_02beforetablesize_20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption_03create_table_20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql

Comment: Okay, give me a bit. So the sort order is (1) file number (2) db-name (3) schema-name. That is doable, but will take using `'-'` and `'_'` as a delimiters to get to the file number. If you have control over the delimiters, `dboption-01stuff-date-time-dbname-dbschema.sql` would make things much easier -- but we can work with what you have -- it will just be messier.

Comment: Thanks David , i can change the filenames that is possible , the only things is the sorting .. I need all the 7 files in order from 1 to 7 for schema level .The schema name can be same for any database , only all the 3 combination makes the files unique, thanks

Comment: You would want `dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914-FOO_PDA-BAR_CDS.sql` so you have *Option*, *fileno_stuff*, *date*, *time*, *dbname*, *dbschema*. *ext*. That would be the ideal format with the `'-'` field delimiter that would make parsing much easier.

Comment: dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-04Export_DDL_AFTER_CHANGE-20200710-092914_PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sh
dboption-05drop_table-20200710-092914_PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-07afterschemasize-20200710-092914_PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-06aftertablesize-20200710-092914_PDA_ORR-CDS_SSO.sql
for some reason out of many combination i tried this one is not coming as expected

Comment: But honestly many many thanks David , that is an awesome knowledge , i am doing a big shell script which has to process files in order based on the db,schema and file number if not the whole script fails , like if a drop file is executed before create then the drop file will completely fail , i have to process 7 files for each db and schema level  and then proceed with next set , many thanks

Comment: if i do that the whole file is collapsed now , awk -F'-' '{print $0" "substr($2,1,match($2,/[^0-9]+/)-1)+0" "$(NF-1)" "substr($NF,1,match($NF,/[.]/)-1)}' listing |  sort -k4  -k2n |  awk '{print $1}' | more
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914_PDA-CDS.sql
Thanks

Comment: Oh yes -- that is a pickle. Wait just a minute. Let me work on this a second more. I see what you are saying. Your FORMAT is not in the order we discussed. `092914_PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sq` there should be a `'-'` between the TIME and DBNAME -- that is causing the problem here.

Comment: Even if have the filename as below , it is collapsed ..awk -F'-' '{print $0" "substr($2,1,match($2,/[^0-9]+/)-1)+0" "$(NF-1)" "substr($NF,1,match($NF,/[.]/)-1)}' listing |  sort -k4  -k2n |  awk '{print $1}' | more
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914-A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914-PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914-A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914-PDA-CDS.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914-A_IS_CRB-CDS.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914-PDA-CDS.sql

Comment: When you fix the filename use the full sort `sort -k4 -k3 -k2n` The only other thing we can do -- if and only if the date and time are **guaranteed** to be the same for each `01 - 07` sequence is to include that as part of the sort if we need another identifier.

Comment: awk -F'-' '{print $0" "substr($2,1,match($2,/[^0-9]+/)-1)+0" "$(NF-1)"  "substr($NF,1,match($NF,/[.]/)-1)}' listing1 |  sort -k4 -k3 -k2n |  awk '{print $1}'
dboption-01beforeschemasize-20200710-092914-PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-02beforetablesize-20200710-092914-PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-03create_table-20200710-092914-PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-04Export_DDL_CHANGE-20200710-092914-PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sh
dboption-05drop_table-20200710-092914-PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-07afterschemasize-20200710-092914-PDA_OPR-CDS_SSO.sql
dboption-06aftertablesize-20200710-092914-PDA_ORR-CDS_SSO.sql

Comment: since the size , i can live with it i think david , i have troubled u enough

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
 sort -t '-' -k2  list
```

It's may be the good solution for you. Tel me if it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mchelabi , 99% works fine only this file is comming on top rest 6 files in order for their own db and schem "dboption_04Export_DDL_AFTER_CHANGE_20200710-092914_A_IS_CRB_CDS.sh"  not sure because this is the only .sh file and rest all 6 files are .sql